# print sequence of double results from integer array java

Tags: java

I'm struggling to learn arrays in Java. I have some code which includes an array of Integer for attendance over 10 weeks with a class size of 15. The task is to output the percentage attendance for each week. I've managed to create a for loop to access each value in the array and I have done what I think is correct to cast these to double so that I can work out the percent of each. I encounter issues when trying to output results. Firstly when trying to println the error is that i has not been initialised. I have i in my for loop and if i take it out of the for loop i get output of 8.0 which is not what I want. Secondly, I would like all results to be numbered 1 to 10 but again the +i+ in println is not working for me and I don't know why. Could someone tell me what I have done wrong with i? Thanks

public class AttendanceTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Integer CLASS_SIZE = 15;
    Integer[] attendances = {10, 14, 12, 9, 11, 15, 12, 13, 8, 14};
   double attendance=0;

   {for(int i=0;i<attendances[i];i++)
         attendance=(double) (attendances[i] / 15)*100;

    System.out.println(+i+attendance );
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The way you currently have it, the calculation is the *only* thing that's controlled by the for loop. The println is not part of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The curly brace must come after the for loop declaration. Additionally, you have to cast attendances[i] to double inside the parentheses, not outside. Thirdly, your solution is adding i to the percentage. You should add a space character in between so it doesn't add the two numbers. Fourthly, the stopping condition for the for loop should be when i is equal to the number of elements in attendances.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Integer CLASS_SIZE = 15;
    Integer[] attendances = {10, 14, 12, 9, 11, 15, 12, 13, 8, 14};
    double attendance;
    for (int i = 0; i < attendances.length; i++) {
        attendance = ((double) attendances[i] / CLASS_SIZE) * 100;
        System.out.println(i + " " + attendance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are casting the result of the computation, but by that point it is too late.  You need to cast `attendances[i]` as a double, so that integer division won't be used.

Answer (score 0):

As you just need to output the attendance of each variable, you should put the print inside of the for-loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Integer CLASS_SIZE = 15;
    Integer[] attendances = {10, 14, 12, 9, 11, 15, 12, 13, 8, 14};

   for(int i = 0; i < attendances.length; i++){
         System.out.println(((double) attendances[i] / 15) * 100 + "% attendance" );
   }
}
```

A few things to note with your code:

1. To get the length of an array, you need to use array.length.
2. The casting of an double variable should be in front of an Integer-variable. This is because when you divide to integers, you will get an integer back. If you divide by a double and a integer, you will get an double back.
3. I would rather divide by CLASS_SIZE instead of hard coding in 15 in your code.
4. The curly braces on your for-loop is supposed to be after it, and encapsle whats in it. Like:

   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
         //What happens when it loops should go in here
          System.out.println("i is now " + i);

   }